# Raspberry Pi & HDMI Switches

Tags: hdmi, switches

I've got a HDMI switch with 3 devices plugged into it - an Apple TV, a PS4 and my Raspberry Pi 2.  The aTV & PS4 both handle themselves quite well & will take control of the signal at the right times.

But when the switch is set to the Pi, nothing seems to be able to take control of the signal. The Pi itself is just showing a black screen while it's in standby.

Is there any way I can make the signal 'less important'? I've not got a clue on this kind of thing so no idea if what I'm asking is a very dumb question!

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with the synchronization signal between Pi and your TV. But see if this helps:

edit `/boot/config.txt`, make sure `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` is uncommented. Reboot.